Polars - check for null in dataframe
I know I can do .null_count() in Polars, which returns a dataframe telling me null count for each column.
d = {"foo":[1,2,3, None], "bar":[4,None, None, 6]}
df_polars_withnull = pl.from_dict(d)

df_polars_withnull.null_count()

would yield a dataframe
foo   bar
  1     2

I want to know if there's any nulls, within the entire dataframe
something like
if any(df_polars_withnull.null_count()):
   print ('has nulls')
else:
   print ('no nulls')

Unfortunately, that doesn't work. What is the correct code here?
This works, but seems a bit ugly
if df_polars_nonull.null_count().sum(axis=1)[0]:
   print ('has nulls')
else:
   print ('no nulls')



I would consider the following approaches idiomatic polars. Note that in both cases, I use pl.DataFrame.item to ensure the output is a bool instead of a pl.DataFrame of shape (1, 1).
Approach 1. Check if sum of null counts are greater than 0.
df.null_count().pipe(sum).item() > 0

Approach 2. Literally check if there exist any null values.
df.select(pl.any_horizontal(pl.all().is_null().any())).item()

Explanation. If df is of shape (n, c), then:

using pl.all().is_null() will give a boolean dataframe of shape (n, c) indicating for each element whether it is null;
using pl.all().is_null().any() will give a boolean dataframe of shape (1, c) indicating for each column whether it contains at least one null;
using pl.any_horizontal(pl.all().is_null().any()) will give a boolean dataframe of shape (1, 1) indicating whether there were any null values in df.


this looks great. But, I'm on version 0.13. Since I don't have item(), should I just get the value using [0]?

@user3240688 item() was only added in polars 0.15.9. In this case, you will likely need to use [0,0].

Thanks. @Hericks And I have a follow up question.   pl.all().is_null().any() makes sense to me. It is returning boolean dataframe of shape (1,c). But why can't I just use df.select() on this expression to look at it? If I try, it gives me error about  DuplicateError: Column with name: 'is_null' has more than one occurrences  It's renaming every column to is_null. I suppose it's something about Polars that I don't understand

@user3240688 Hmm, I just tried in an environment with version 0.13 installed and selection works without any problems. I am using df.select(pl.all().is_null().any()).

Maybe this is what you are looking for:
df_polars_withnull.null_count().sum_horizontal()


What about reshaping to a single column with unpivot, then running is_null+any:
df_polars_withnull.unpivot()['value'].is_null().any()

Or:
any(df_polars_withnull.select(pl.all().is_null().any()).row(0))

Output: True
